# What happens when I call new?

Tags: d

What happens exactly if I call new (for arrays and/or objects) in DMD?

For example `int[] data = new int[number];` or `new MyObject();` ?

Where can I find the sources of the stuff that is going on in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation for creating objects is in Druntime, specifically in `rt.lifetime`.

Class creation is done using [`_d_newclass`](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/druntime/blob/master/src/rt/lifetime.d#L58-L105), and array creation is done using [the `_d_newarray` functions](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/druntime/blob/master/src/rt/lifetime.d#L755-L859).

Comment: after looking it up (or refreshing memory) this means that the GC functionality depends on type information (if you call it with the default new op), hmmm

Comment: Yes, it does. Otherwise, it would be unable to be precise in any degree, and would need to consider any machine word as a possible pointer.